# DNS Records for expired domains

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name

Is there anyway to look up the ds record for an expired domain name? I need to find the dns record/information relating to an expired domain name but the domain has already expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to look it up at the registrar, then probably not. You may be able to find it if you owned it and you log in to the management interface for the registrar that had it, but even that is unlikely.